# Query SUPER type to extract array element

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm transferring Google Analytics data from BigQuery to Redshift. I have created a table with many `SUPER` fields to be able to have the same structure as Big Query.

The problem I have encountered has to do with a field (`customDimensions`) that contains information in the shape:

```json
[{"index":48,"value":"/en"},{"index":103,"value":"US"}]
```

I want to query a column that contains the value associated witih index 48.

In Big Query I could do it by doing:

```sql
SELECT
(SELECT value FROM p.customDimensions WHERE index=48) AS attribute
FROM sessions p
;
```

I have to do the same with many attributes (each one in one column)

Do you know if there is any way of doing this in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest your column https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest

```sql
select *, custom_dimension."value"
from sessions p,
     p."customDimensions" as custom_dimension
where custom_dimension."index"::int = 48;
```